# Classification in real time without prior knowledge of the number of classes

Tags: real-time, cluster-analysis

Is there an implemented algorithm (with python/R or java in preference) that can classify incoming data from an unknown generator with absolutely no prior knowledge or assumption.

**For example:**

Let G be a generator of 2d vectors that generate one vector in each second.

What we know, and nothing else, is that this vectors are separable into clusters in space (euclidean distance).

**Question:** How can I classify my data in real time so that at each iteration, the algorithm propose clusters?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Comment: @ChrisHeald oups that would work, BUT **without prior knowledge of the number of classes**

Comment: That's kind of meaningless; how do you define a class? Without that constraint, the optimal solution is 1 class per datapoint, with each datapoint being prototypical of its class.

Comment: Yes but I specified "What we know, and nothing else, is that this vectors are separable into clusters in space (euclidean distance).". After all, 1 class per datapoint is an evident solution the same thing as 1 class fr all.

Comment: "separable into clusters in space" just means that they aren't coincident, though. The important question is _how_ do you decide how to partition them? That infers some manner of class selection, which requires knowledge of a class's characteristics and what makes it distinct from another class.

Comment: _how do you decide how to partition them?_ that's my question.

Comment: That's entirely dependent on your problem domain. Given a set of data, how would you partition it? What features make a piece of data belong to one cluster or the other? Those are the sorts of questions you'll have to answer in order to come up with any viable approach.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also in the process of searching for something related to [Data stream clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_stream_clustering) and I found some papers and code:

- [Aforementioned survey](http://charuaggarwal.net/ssurvey.pdf) by Charu C. Aggarwal from [aforementioned book](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.360.3651&rep=rep1&type=pdf);
- [Density-Based Clustering over an Evolving Data Stream with Noise.](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ester/papers/SDM2006.DenStream.final.pdf) by Feng Cao et al., proposes DenStream; [here](https://github.com/XiongQibetterwood/DenStream) is a git repo for that (Matlab);
- [Density-Based Clustering for Real-Time Stream Data](http://www1.cse.wustl.edu/~ychen/public/sigproc-sp.pdf) by Yixin Chen, Li Tu, proposes the D-Stream framework ([2008 version](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=BBF94DFFC1C7928CA64F2691625601BB?doi=10.1.1.141.1264&rep=rep1&type=pdf) called `Stream data clustering based on grid density and attraction`); There is a DD-Stream that I can't find a pdf for in `A grid and density-based clustering algorithm for processing data stream` by Jia.
- [A Fast and Stable Incremental Clustering Algorithm](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~itamar/Papers/ITNG2010.pdf) by Steven Young et al. focuses on clustering as an unsupervised learning process;
- [Self-Adaptive Anytime Stream Clustering](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Thomas_Seidl2/publication/220765168_Self-Adaptive_Anytime_Stream_Clustering/links/09e4150b85c306fd52000000.pdf) by Philipp Kranen et al. has ClusTree and [this](https://github.com/anantsubramanian/dclustree-stream-clustering) git repo implements DClusTree;
- [Pre-clustering algorithm for anomaly detection and clustering that uses variable size buckets](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SharmaManish/Clustering/master/paper%20clustering%20rait%202012.pdf) by Manish Sharma et al. is more recent and may be relevant ([git repo](https://github.com/SharmaManish/Clustering) of the author);

[This paper](http://researchcommons.waikato.ac.nz/bitstream/handle/10289/4934/Holmes%20Bifet%20Pfahringer%20JMLR%202010.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y) is about [MOA](http://moa.cms.waikato.ac.nz/) (Massive Online Analysis) states that it implements some of the above (StreamKM++, CluStream, ClusTree, Den-Stream, D-Stream and CobWeb). I believe that D-Stream is work in progress/wishful thinking (is not part of the pre-release available from their website). [MOA](http://moa.cms.waikato.ac.nz/) is written in Java, [here](https://github.com/cran/streamMOA) is streamMOA package.

The code in [this](https://github.com/shivareddyiirs/Clustering-Stream-Data) repository seems to be a Python implementation of the D-Stream but, [according to the author](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/moa-users/DfC8c_YxE6I/Wvvp4PEokncJ), it is slow.

Also, [stream](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stream/vignettes/stream.pdf) is a framework for data stream clustering research with R.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking about "Stream mining" here.

Read this article

Chapter 10: *A Survey of Stream Clustering Algorithms.*
Charu C. Aggarwal, IBM T. J. Watson Research Center, Yorktown Heights, NY

This can be found in the 2014 book

DATA CLUSTERING- Algorithms and Applications, Edited by Charu C. Aggarwal and Chandan K. Reddy.

In that chapter the "CluStream" framework is described. This project is from 2002, and it is based on the BIRCH algorithm from 1997 which is a "Micro-Clustering" approach. The algorithm creates an index structure on the fly.

Considering that there are few BIRCH implementations, 
there is probably no open-source CluStream algorithm/framework available.

Here's a [Github repo](https://github.com/perdisci/jbirch/) with a BIRCH implementation in Java - although I haven't tried this code, and that repo is not for "stream mining".

All this just appeared on my radar because I just recently participated in the Coursera MOOC on cluster analysis.

Answer (score 0):

There are no assumption free methods.

You are asking for magic to happen.

1. Never blindly use a clustering result. Do not use clustering on a stream. Instead, **analyze and correct any clustering result before deployment**.
2. Watch out for hidden assumptions. For example, assumptions that clusters are convex, distance based (why is Euclidean distance the coorect choice?), have the same size or extend, are separated (by what?) or shape. **Whenever you design a method, you make assumptions on what is interesting.**
3. Wothout assumption, anything is a "clustering"!